# Handle large eqn in Latex

Tags: equations

I want to automatically write very large expression like the following

```
\mathbf{B_{3,1(3)}}(x)=  3+\frac{\pi ^2}{4}+\frac{13 x}{8}+\frac{1}{2 \epsilon ^2}+\frac{6+x}{4 \epsilon }-\frac{\left(-1+x^2\right) G(-1,x)}{2
   x}-G(0,-1,x)+\epsilon  \left(-\frac{13 \left(-1+x^2\right) G(-1,x)}{4 x}+\left(-\frac{2}{x}+2 x\right) G(-1,-1,x)+\left(-3+\frac{1}{2
   x}-x\right) G(0,-1,x)+4 G(0,-1,-1,x)-G(0,0,-1,x)+\frac{1}{48} \left(180+345 x+6 \pi ^2 (6+x)-64 \zeta (3)\right)\right)+\epsilon ^2
   \left(-\frac{21}{8}+\frac{7 \pi ^4}{80}+\frac{1}{16} \pi ^2 (24+13 x)-\frac{\left(115+2 \pi ^2\right) \left(-1+x^2\right) G(-1,x)}{8
   x}+\frac{13 \left(-1+x^2\right) G(-1,-1,x)}{x}+\frac{1}{4} \left(-24-2 \pi ^2+\frac{13}{x}-26 x\right) G(0,-1,x)+\left(\frac{8}{x}-8
   x\right) G(-1,-1,-1,x)+\left(-\frac{3}{x}+3 x\right) G(-1,0,-1,x)+\left(12-\frac{2}{x}+4 x\right) G(0,-1,-1,x)+\left(-3+\frac{1}{2
   x}-x\right) G(0,0,-1,x)-16 G(0,-1,-1,-1,x)+6 G(0,-1,0,-1,x)+4 G(0,0,-1,-1,x)-G(0,0,0,-1,x)+x \left(\frac{865}{32}-\frac{2 \zeta
   (3)}{3}\right)-4 \zeta (3)\right)+\epsilon ^3 \left(\frac{\left(115+2 \pi ^2\right) \left(-1+x^2\right) G(-1,-1,x)}{2
   x}+\left(\frac{52}{x}-52 x\right) G(-1,-1,-1,x)+\frac{39 \left(-1+x^2\right) G(-1,0,-1,x)}{2 x}+\left(24+2 \pi ^2-\frac{13}{x}+26
   x\right) G(0,-1,-1,x)+\frac{1}{4} \left(-24-2 \pi ^2+\frac{13}{x}-26 x\right) G(0,0,-1,x)+\frac{32 \left(-1+x^2\right)
   G(-1,-1,-1,-1,x)}{x}+\left(\frac{12}{x}-12 x\right) G(-1,-1,0,-1,x)+\left(\frac{12}{x}-12 x\right) G(-1,0,-1,-1,x)+\left(-\frac{3}{x}+3
   x\right) G(-1,0,0,-1,x)+8 \left(-6+\frac{1}{x}-2 x\right) G(0,-1,-1,-1,x)+\left(18-\frac{3}{x}+6 x\right)
   G(0,-1,0,-1,x)+\left(12-\frac{2}{x}+4 x\right) G(0,0,-1,-1,x)+\left(-3+\frac{1}{2 x}-x\right) G(0,0,0,-1,x)+64 G(0,-1,-1,-1,-1,x)-24
   G(0,-1,-1,0,-1,x)-24 G(0,-1,0,-1,-1,x)+6 G(0,-1,0,0,-1,x)-16 G(0,0,-1,-1,-1,x)+6 G(0,0,-1,0,-1,x)+4
   G(0,0,0,-1,-1,x)-G(0,0,0,0,-1,x)-\text{M48xM} \left(\left(-1+x^2\right) G(-1,x) \left(2595+78 \pi ^2-64 \zeta
   (3)\right)\right)+\text{M24xM} \left(G(0,-1,x) \left(345-690 x^2-6 \pi ^2 \left(-1+6 x+2 x^2\right)+4 x (-45+16 \zeta
   (3))\right)\right)+\frac{1}{960} \left(42 \pi ^4 (6+x)+x (89565-4160 \zeta (3))+10 \pi ^2 (180+345 x-64 \zeta (3))-12 (3255+640 \zeta
   (3)+256 \zeta (5))\right)\right)
```

I have used `dmath*` environment but does not give proper formatting.

[image]

I want a formatting like the following representative image

[image]

It is impossible to cut by `\\` for a lot of line. Is there any package which can do that?

Comment: What is your full minimal working example?

Answer (score 3):

The equation is, to state the obvious, quite long and not easy to parse visually. Your readers may appreciate if you do part of the parsing job by pointing out that the expression for `\mathbf{B}_{3,1(3)}(x)` consists of four main additive components called, say, `A_0` through `A_3`, with each component headed by a corresponding power of `\epsilon`, i.e, `\epsilon^0=1` through `\epsilon^3`.

I would further like to suggest that you (a) use a single `align*` environment and insert line breaks manually and (b) replace all `\left` and `\right` auto-sizing directives with suitably-chosen `\Bigl`, `\Bigr`, `\biggl`, and `\biggr` directives. Oh, and I'd also run `\allowdisplaybreaks` in order to permit page breaks, if and when needed, in the 25-row equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as appropriate
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment and '\intertext' macro

\begin{document}

\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{B}_{3,1(3)}(x) &= A_0 + A_1 + A_2 + A_3 \\
\intertext{where}
A_0&=\smash[t]{3+\frac{\pi^2}{4}
     +\frac{13 x}{8}
     +\frac{1}{2\epsilon^2}
     +\frac{6+x}{4\epsilon }
     -\frac{(-1+x^2) G(-1,x)}{2x}}
     -G(0,-1,x) \,, \\[2\jot]
A_1&=\epsilon  
   \biggl[
     -\frac{13 (-1+x^2) G(-1,x)}{4 x}
     +\Bigl(-\frac{2}{x}+2 x\Bigr) G(-1,-1,x) \\
   &\quad +\Bigl(-3+\frac{1}{2x}-x\Bigr) G(0,-1,x)
     +4 G(0,-1,-1,x)
     -G (0,0,-1,x) \\
   &\quad +\frac{1}{48} \bigl(180+345 x+6\pi^2 (6+x)-64 \zeta(3)\bigr)
   \biggr] \,,\\[2\jot]
A_2&=\epsilon^2
   \biggl[
     -\frac{21}{8}
     +\frac{7\pi ^4}{80}
     +\frac{1}{16}\pi^2 (24+13 x)
     -\frac{(115+2\pi^2) (-1+x^2) G(-1,x)}{8x} \\
   &\quad +\frac{13 (-1+x^2) G(-1,-1,x)}{x}
     +\frac{1}{4} \Bigl(-24-2\pi^2+\frac{13}{x}-26 x\Bigr) G(0,-1,x) \\
   &\quad+\Bigl(\frac{8}{x}-8x\Bigr) G(-1,-1,-1,x)
     +\Bigl(-\frac{3}{x}+3x\Bigr) G(-1,0,-1,x) \\
   &\quad+\Bigl(12-\frac{2}{x}+4 x\Bigr) G(0,-1,-1,x)
     +\Bigl(-3+\frac{1}{2x}-x\Bigr) G(0,0,-1,x) \\
   &\quad-16 G(0,-1,-1,-1,x) 
     +6 G(0,-1,0,-1,x)
     +4 G(0,0,-1,-1,x) \\
   &\quad -G(0,0,0,-1,x)
     +x \Bigl(\frac{865}{32}-\frac{2 \zeta(3)}{3}\Bigr)
     -4 \zeta(3)
   \biggr] \,,\text{ and} \\[2\jot]
A_3&=\epsilon ^3 
   \biggl[
     \frac{(115+2\pi^2) (-1+x^2) G(-1,-1,x)}{2 x}
     +\Bigl(\frac{52}{x}-52 x\Bigr) G(-1,-1,-1,x) \\
   &\quad+\frac{39 (-1+x^2) G(-1,0,-1,x)}{2 x}
     +\Bigl(24+2\pi^2-\frac{13}{x}+26x\Bigr) G(0,-1,-1,x) \\
   &\quad+\frac{1}{4} \Bigl(-24-2\pi^2+\frac{13}{x}-26 x\Bigr) G(0,0,-1,x) \\
   &\quad+\frac{32 (-1+x^2)G(-1,-1,-1,-1,x)}{x}
     +\Bigl(\frac{12}{x}-12 x\Bigr) G(-1,-1,0,-1,x) \\
   &\quad+\Bigl(\frac{12}{x}-12 x\Bigr) G(-1,0,-1,-1,x)
     +\Bigl(-\frac{3}{x}+3x\Bigr) G(-1,0,0,-1,x) \\
   &\quad+8 \Bigl(-6+\frac{1}{x}-2 x\Bigr) G(0,-1,-1,-1,x)
     +\Bigl(18-\frac{3}{x}+6 x\Bigr)G(0,-1,0,-1,x) \\
   &\quad+\Bigl(12-\frac{2}{x}+4 x\Bigr) G(0,0,-1,-1,x)
     +\Bigl(-3+\frac{1}{2 x}-x\Bigr) G(0,0,0,-1,x) \\
   &\quad+64 G(0,-1,-1,-1,-1,x)
     -24 G(0,-1,-1,0,-1,x) \\
   &\quad-24 G(0,-1,0,-1,-1,x)
     +6 G(0,-1,0,0,-1,x) \\
   &\quad-16 G(0,0,-1,-1,-1,x)
     +6 G(0,0,-1,0,-1,x) \\
   &\quad+4 G(0,0,0,-1,-1,x)
     -G(0,0,0,0,-1,x) \\
   &\quad-\mathrm{M48xM} \Bigl((-1+x^2) G(-1,x) 
     \bigl(2595+78\pi^2-64 \zeta(3)\bigr) \Bigr) \\
   &\quad+\mathrm{M24xM} \Bigl(G(0,-1,x) 
     \bigl(345-690 x^2-6\pi^2 (-1+6 x+2 x^2)
     +4 x (-45+16 \zeta(3))\bigr)\Bigr) \\
   &\quad+\frac{1}{960} \Bigl(42\pi ^4 (6+x)
     +x \bigl(89565-4160 \zeta(3)\bigr)
     +10\pi^2 \bigl(180+345 x-64 \zeta(3)\bigr) \\
   &\qquad -12 \bigl(3255+640 \zeta(3)+256 \zeta(5)\bigr) \Bigr)
  \biggr]\,.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very long equation, which you obviously cannot fit in a single line. Even if you divide it into separate lines, you are going to end up with multiple pages.

By default, LaTeX does not break equations over pages. You have to add `\displaybreak[<n>]` at the point where you expect a line break, right before `\\`. `n` is in the range between 0 (no line breaks) to 4 and denotes how much desired the line break is at that point. You could also append following macro in preamble `\allowdisplaybreaks[<n>]`, which is the same as adding `\displaybreak[n]` to all equations. BTW it's recommended to use `\allowdisplaybreaks[n]` with small values and `\displaybreak[n]` with higher values.

This eq. needs a certain *structure* either by using `align` environment or a number of nested inner environments, s.a. `aligned` or `split`. There's plenty of info on this site but ultimately I would suggest to read the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) documentation. In general, I would recommend using nested `aligned`. However, because of the length of the whole expression, I think it is required to use one big `align*` with multiple columns and potential line breaks at each line. Notice I have added `\mathrlap{}` in order to avoid pushing everything to the right by the middle column. You can see the structure is grouped by `\epsilon` but you can take over from here and make your own form.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}    % for \mathrlap{}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mleftright}   % for \mleftX and \mrightX, improved and recommended versions of  `\leftX and `\rightX, s.a. \left( or \left[
\usepackage{kantlipsum}   % For \kant[n] to insert dummy texts

\allowdisplaybreaks[1]   % Adds \displaybreak[1] in equations, which could be superseded by a local \displaybreak[n] 
\newcommand{\M}[1]{\mathrm{M}#1\mathord{\times}\mathrm{M}}


\begin{document}
% This macro redefines \leftX and \rightX to their improved versions. Alternatively, use \mleftX and \mrightX
%   X denotes symbols, s.a. (, [, or \{ etc. 
\mleftright

\kant[3-4]
\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{B_{3, 1(3)}}(x) &= \mathrlap{3
                            + \frac{\pi ^2}{4}
                            + \frac{13x}{8}
                            + \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2}
                            + \frac{6 + x}{4\epsilon}
                            - \frac{(-1 + x^2) G(-1, x)}{2x}
                            - G(0, -1, x)} && \\
                          &\phantom{={}} + \epsilon \Biggl(\mathrlap{- \frac{13(-1 + x^2) G(-1, x)}{4x}} && \\
                          &&& + \biggl(-\frac{2}{x} + 2x) G(-1, -1, x\biggr) \\
                          &&& + \biggl(-3 + \frac{1}{2x} - x) G(0, -1, x\biggr) \\
                          &&& + 4G(0, -1, -1, x) - G(0, 0, -1, x) \\
                          &&& + \frac{1}{48} \Bigl(180 + 345x + 6\pi^2 (6 + x) -64\zeta(3)\Bigr) \Biggr) \\
                          &\phantom{={}} + \epsilon^2 \Biggl(\mathrlap{-\frac{21}{8} + \frac{7\pi^4}{80} + \frac{1}{16} \pi^2 (24 + 13x)} && \\
                          &&& - \frac{(115 + 2\pi^2) (-1 + x^2) G(-1, x)}{8x} \\
                          &&& + \frac{13(-1 + x^2) G(-1, -1, x)}{x} \\
                          &&& + \frac{1}{4} \biggl(-24 - 2\pi^2 + \frac{13}{x} -26x\biggr) G(0, -1, x) \\
                          &&& + \biggl(\frac{8}{x} -8x\biggr) G(-1, -1, -1, x)
                              + \biggl(-\frac{3}{x} + 3x\biggr) G(-1, 0, -1, x) \\
                          &&& + (12 - \frac{2}{x} + 4x) G(0, -1, -1, x) \\
                          &&& + (-3 + \frac{1}{2x} - x) G(0, 0, -1, x) \\
                          &&& - 16G(0, -1, -1, -1, x) + 6G(0, -1, 0, -1, x) \\
                          &&& + 4G(0, 0, -1, -1, x) - G(0, 0, 0, -1, x) \\
                          &&& + x\biggl(\frac{865}{32} - \frac{2\zeta(3)}{3}\biggr) - 4\zeta (3) \Biggr) \\
                          &\phantom{={}} + \epsilon^3 \Biggl(\mathrlap{\frac{(115 + 2 \pi ^2) (-1 + x^2) G(-1, -1, x)}{2x}} && \\
                          &&& + (\frac{52}{x} -52x) G( -1, -1, -1, x) \\
                          &&& + \frac{39(-1 + x^2) G(-1, 0, -1, x)}{2x} \\
                          &&& + (24 + 2 \pi^2 - \frac{13}{x} + 26x) G(0, -1, -1, x) \\
                          &&& + \frac{1}{4} (-24 -2 \pi ^2 + \frac{13}{x} -26x) G(0, 0, -1, x) \\
                          &&& + \frac{32 (-1 + x^2) G(-1, -1, -1, -1, x)}{x} \\
                          &&& + \biggl(\frac{12}{x} -12x\biggr) G(-1, -1, 0, -1, x) \\
                          &&& + \biggl(\frac{12}{x} -12x\biggr) G(-1, 0, -1, -1, x)
                              + \biggl(-\frac{3}{x} + 3x\biggr) G( -1, 0, 0, -1, x) \\
                          &&& + 8(-6 + \frac{1}{x} - 2x) G(0, -1, -1, -1, x) \\
                          &&& + (18 - \frac{3}{x} + 6x) G(0, -1, 0, -1, x) \\
                          &&& + (12 - \frac{2}{x} + 4x) G(0, 0, -1, -1, x) \\
                          &&& + ( -3 + \frac{1}{2x} - x) G(0, 0, 0, -1, x) \\
                          &&& + 64 G(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, x) - 24 G(0, -1, -1, 0, -1, x) \\
                          &&& - 24 G(0, -1, 0, -1, -1, x) + 6 G(0, -1, 0, 0, -1, x) \\
                          &&& - 16 G(0, 0, -1, -1, -1, x) + 6 G(0, 0, -1, 0, -1, x) \\
                          &&& + 4 G(0, 0, 0, -1, -1, x) - G(0, 0, 0, 0, -1, x) \\
                          &&& - \M{48} \bigl((-1 + x^2) G(-1, x) (2595 + 78 \pi^2 - 64\zeta (3))\bigr) \\
                          &&& + \M{24} \bigl(G(0, -1, x) (345 -690x^2 -6 \pi ^2 ( -1 + 6x + 2x^2\bigr) \\
                          &&& + 4x ( -45 + 16 \zeta (3)))) + \frac{1}{960} \Bigl(
                              \begin{aligned}[t]
                                & 42\pi^4 (6 + x) + x (89565 -4160 \zeta (3)) \\
                                & + 10\pi^2 (180 + 345x -64 \zeta (3)) \\
                                & - 12(3255 + 640 \zeta (3) + 256 \zeta (5)) \Bigr) \smash{\Biggr)}
                              \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]